# How to get Logger in void Main with Ninject.Extensions.Logging?

Tags: c#, ninject, nlog, ninject-extensions

I'm using `Ninject` for my DI and `Ninject.Extensions.Logging` (with NLog) for Logger injection. I want to get an instance of Logger in my Main void at the start of the program.

I tried this code:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var logger = new StandardKernel(new NLogModule()).Get<ILogger>();
}
```

But I get an error `Error loading module 'Ninject.Extensions.Logging.NLog2.NLogModule' of type NLogModule`.

How can I get a Logger instance in this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extensions are loaded automatically. You cant load it again manually. Just use

```
new StandardKernel().Get<ILoggerFactory>().GetCurrentClassLogger();
```